# How to determine whether "to" is needed or not?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, bare-infinitives

"I can help improve your skills." 
"I can help to improve your skills."
Which of this sentences is correct? 
How do you decide to put "to" or omit?

Comment: Both are OK. The complement to "help" can be an infinitive phrase with or without "to".

Answer (score 1):

The infinitive form sounds just a bit off just to my ear, but it is not incorrect. The first form could be argued to "imply" the word "to." In either case, you're defining what can be helped, and either construct would work. I prefer and would recommend the former, but neither is categorically wrong.

Answer (score 0):

How to determine whether "to" is needed?

I can help (to) improve your skills.

In verb patterns with to infinitive, you can either put or omit "to" after help.   In other words, if you use the verb "help" in the sense of making it easier for somebody to do something or for something to happen, you can put or omit "to" before an infinitive.  You omit "to" more in informal and spoken English than in formal English. Look at the following examples:

I can help you (to) improve your skills.

I can help (to) improve your skills.

However, if somebody uses "cannot help" to convey the sense of his inability to prevent himself from doing something, then you cannot use an infinitive with/without to. Instead, you use the -ing form.  For example,
It's so awful that I can't help laughing.  However, you can always use an infinitive without "to" with the phrase "cannot but help" such as it's so awful that I cannot help but laugh.

Answer (score 0):

This is a case of language change; the normal construction was "to help <somebody> to do <something>" ( to help + to-infinitive). Nowadays to help is felt almost as a modal verb and mostly you find the bare infinitive: "to help <somebody> do <something>". But if you use the older construction it is not wrong.

http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/help_1?q=help

BrE: Whereas OALD has both possibilities, in AmE the to-infinitive has become dated. AHD has only the bare infinitive.

https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=help&submit.x=50&submit.y=30